# What is the difference between getFirst() and peekFirst() in Java's LinkedList?

Tags: java, linked-list

In Java's LinkedList implementation, I see two methods which seems to me like having identical functions.

`getFirst()` --Returns the first element in this list.

`peekFirst()` --Retrieves, but does not remove, the first element of this list, or returns null if this list is empty.

Both of them get the pointer to the First element in the LinkedList without making any changes to it. Then, what's the difference ?

The only difference I see is that `peekFirst` returns `null` if the list is empty and `getFirst` throws a `NoSuchElementException` if the list is empty. What was the use of such a design pattern ?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html. Check Oracle documentation.

Comment: Do you mind if I change the title to "What is the difference between getFirst() and peekFirst() in Java's LinkedList?" What you have is a little vague (it sounds like you're talking about all of the methods in the title, and it's not clear from the title exactly what you're asking about them)

Comment: @DennisMeng Sure, you can do that.

Comment: This question is really about `Deque` (which `LinkedList` implements) and not `LinkedList` directly.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Java introduced `LinkedList` in version 1.2. This is when the `getFirst` method has been provided. This message threw `NoSuchElementException` when the list is empty, causing programmers to do an extra check before the call:

```
Element e = null;
if (!myList.isEmpty()) {
     e = myList.getFirst();
}
```

This was an inconvenience, which has been fixed in Java version 1.6 by adding the `peekFirst` method and other methods of the `Dequeue<T>` interface.

Comment: Wouldn't we still need to check for null in the result? Instead of doing this before the call, we're doing this after the call.

Answer (score 8):

Only one reson:
1) It reduces the Exception Handling while development

```
 public E peekFirst() {
     if (size==0)
        return null;

     return getFirst();
 }
```

Above is the implementation of peekFirst(), it just check the size ZERO, and returns NULL instead of throwing Exception

Answer (score 3):

LinkedList is a Deque. Deque API defines methods which exist in two forms: one throws an exception if the operation fails, the other returns a special value (either null or false, depending on the operation).

Answer (score 0):

If your `LinkedList` has data then there is no difference, but if your `LinkedList` is empty then the `peekFirst()` method returns null. It doesn't throw any errors or exceptions but `getFirst()` method throws an exception if the list is empty.